# SPF record validation - best guess only

Tags: domain-name-system, email, spf

I administrate the domain [mydomain.com] which was until now only used for handling mail through Google Mail/Google Apps.

Now I added a server which should be part of the domain without changing the primary purpose. I want the server to be able to send simple administrative mail, so I installed and configured sendmail.

When I send testmails to another Google Mail address the mail gets through but I get this header information:

```
Received-SPF: pass (google.com: best guess record for domain of
[myuser]@[myhost].[mydomain].com designates [myipv6address]
as permitted sender) client-ip=[myipv6address];
```

Now of course I want the validation to pass without guessing but I have probably something wrong in my DNS record.

```
$TTL 86400
@   IN SOA [mynameserver1]. (
    2013101002   ; serial
    14400        ; refresh
    1800         ; retry
    604800       ; expire
    86400 )      ; minimum

@            IN NS      [mynameserver3].
@            IN NS      [mynameserver2].
@            IN NS      [mynameserver1].

@            IN A       [myipv4address]
[myhost]     IN A       [myipv4address]

@            IN AAAA    [myipv6address]
[myhost]     IN AAAA    [myipv6address]

@            IN MX 1    ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM.
@            IN MX 5    ALT1.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM.
@            IN MX 5    ALT2.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM.
@            IN MX 10   ASPMX2.GOOGLEMAIL.COM.
@            IN MX 10   ASPMX3.GOOGLEMAIL.COM.
@            IN TXT     "v=spf1 a:[myhost].[mydomain].com ip4:[myipv4address]
                        ip6:[myipv6address] include:_spf.google.com ~all"
```

I can't find the error and would appreciate any help.

Best regards,

Thomas

Comment: What is the problem you are having? Your post does not describe any problem.

Comment: The problem is that I expect the receiving mail server not only to "guess" that the sending host is valid. I think other providers may be stricter and classify the mail as spam.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You sent email from an address which contains a subdomain of your domain. Your domain has an SPF record, but the subdomain does not. Thus Google makes a "best guess" that your domain's SPF record should be used. This violates [the specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4408), under which your subdomain would not be considered to have an SPF record, but it usually reflects what senders (whose mail systems are misconfigured) intended.

Comment: Shouldn't this be addressed by the A and AAAA entry for the hostname and the hostname in the spf line?

Comment: No, you misunderstand. Your hostname, what you call `[myhost]`, is missing an SPF record.

Comment: So I should add an additional line like: `[myhost]            IN TXT     "v=spf1 a:[myhost].[mydomain].com ip4:[myipv4address]
                        ip6:[myipv6address] include:_spf.google.com ~all"` ?

Comment: Yes, if that's the record you want.

Comment: I changed my sendmail.cf to masquerade as [mydomain].com instead of [myhost].[mydomain].com now and everything works as intended. Thanks for showing me the right direction!